# Determine southwest and northeast point for bounds in Google maps

Tags: google-maps

I have a set of markers on google map (say 6). Now i want to zoom in only to certain level that displays all markers well for that i used getBoundsZoomLevel().

Problem is I dont know how to determine the BOUNDS from array of latitude and longitude.

Can somebody tell me how to determine south-west and north-east point for a bound???

I found this one post but i m not able to understand it as i dont know what is DIST...
[SouthWest and NorthEast Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605805/southwest-and-northeast-points)

Comment: so you want to restrict the user from zooming in to a point where all markers arent visible?

Comment: DIST is the distance or radius you want around your point. It will basically determine how large your rectangle is.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at LatLngBounds
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLngBounds

As you added new LatLngs you can call `extend(point:LatLng)`, the bounds will then contain all of your added LatLngs.

Comment: hi thanks for replying. I already use extend when i am adding markers. What i want to do is when a user selects 2 or 3 or more markers then i want to zoom map in such a way that contains all the SELECTED MARKERS. so for this i need to determine northeast and southwest points from arrays of latitude and longitude

Comment: So, create a new LatLngBounds object and add the markers that the user selects into it.

Answer (score 0):

This is in Objective C, Hope the logic helps you:

```
-(NSArray *)calculateLongLatDegreesInMeters:(CLLocationDegrees)latitude {
float lat = M_PI * latitude / 180;

// Constants for calculating lengths

float m1 = 111132.92;

float m2 = -559.82;

float m3 = 1.175;

float m4 = -0.0023;

float p1 = 111412.84;

float p2 = -93.5;

float p3 = 0.118;

float eq1 = m1 + (m2 * cos(2 * lat)) + (m3 * cos(4 * lat));

float latitudeDegreeInMeters = eq1 + (m4 * cos(6 * lat));

float longitudeDegreeInMeters = (p1 * cos(lat)) + (p2 * cos(3 * lat)) +    (p3 * cos(5 * lat));

NSString *latDegInMtr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",latitudeDegreeInMeters];
NSString *lonDegInMtr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",longitudeDegreeInMeters];


NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:latDegInMtr,lonDegInMtr, nil];



return arr; //(latitudeDegreeInMeters, longitudeDegreeInMeters)
}
```